# Linux Cinnamon Mint - Remember window positions and sizes

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon

In Linux Cinnamon Mint 17.3, I would like to lock in the size and position of windows for specific apps, especially Nemo or Nautilus.  How might I do that?

Comment: Bug still there in 20+. Cinnamon forgets the accurate position of a window when it gets maximized and then restored to the previous state. Cinnamon adds a small space between the window and the screen border, and one has to drag it to the border again in order to have it occupy exactly half the space of the screen.

Comment: Mint 22 using Mate still has problem-saving window size and positions

Answer (score 1):

You can now (Mint 19, not sure when it was added) go to System Settings -> Windows -> Behavior and change these settings. Automatic appears to remember from my short experience with it.

Comment: `Automatic` works only for some applications, e.g. Nemo and Chrome. It doesn't work for many others, e.g. Terminal and Xreader. Tested on Linux Mint 19.3 Cinnamon.

Comment: `Automatic` works for many applications, but does not work on Firefox. Any ideas on how to get this to work for Firefox?

Comment: Does not work for Mint 22

Answer (score -1):

Go in the Windows settings. Here, go to Behavior.
There change "position of new windows" to cursor. And all the switches are on (on their left position).
Windows won't now always in the middle of your screen.

Hope it helps...

Comment: This doesn't answer the original poster's question. It doesn't appear that Cinnamon has the option to lock the size and position of windows.

Comment: Mate has a similar problem with saving window positions and sizes